# How can I play a sound while other lines of code execute simultaneously?

Tags: python, windows, while-loop

I want my code to do this, but with music playing in the background:

```
import time 
while True:
    print ('ligma')
    time.sleep(1.5)
```

I tried this:

```
import time 
import winsound
while True:
    print ('ligma')
    time.sleep(1.5)
    winsound.PlaySound("dank", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
```

but, it repeats the sound **then** repeats the word. I am expecting it to repeat the word and play the sound at the same time.

Comment: Your application is single threaded. The playsound function has an option to make it multi-threaded i.e. return immediately and allow the loop to continue. See the winsound doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html : SND_ASYNC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to play the sound on another thread, so your other code can be executing at the same time.

```
import time
import winsound
from threading import Thread

def play_sound():
    winsound.PlaySound("dank", winsound.SND_ALIAS)

while True:
    thread = Thread(target=play_sound)
    thread.start()
    print ('ligma')
    time.sleep(1.5)
```

EDIT:
I have moved the thread declaration into the loop. My initial answer had it created outside of the loop, which caused a RuntimeError. Learn more here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start

Comment: @DerekLeyman You were probably getting an error about a thread only being able to be started once. I have adjusted the code, so that the thread is created within the loop. Try this and let me know if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It's called asynchronous sound, and the [`winsound.SND_ASYNC`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/winsound.html#winsound.SND_ASYNC) flag on `PlaySound` will let you play a sound while your code continues to execute:

```
winsound.PlaySound("dank", winsound.SND_ALIAS|winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

From memory, this will give you a single sound channel i.e. playing other sounds will cut off any currently playing sounds. If more concurrent playback is required, something like [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/) is required.

Answer (score 0):

There is an optional second argument that is set to True automatically. To play music asynchronously set that argument to False.

```
playsound('file',False)
```