# How can I run two different code in Python at the same time?

Tags: python

I want to run winsound and print an output at the same time. Here's my code:

```
winsound.PlaySound(filename, winsound.SND_FILENAME)
print('a')
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Try to add [`SND_ASYNC`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html#winsound.SND_ASYNC) flag using bitwice OR (`|`).

Comment: No need to. Audio always has a little delay, so the user won't notice the difference.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52770847/8402369) should help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use threading as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52769618/how-can-i-play-a-sound-while-other-lines-of-code-execute-simultaneously) answer.

```py
import winsound
from threading import Thread

def play_sound():
    winsound.PlaySound(filename, winsound.FILENAME)

thread = Thread(target=play_sound)
thread.start()
print ('a')
```

Comment: Why do you put eternal loop there?

Comment: A process might be better because you can terminate it easily if necessary

Answer (score 0):

pip install multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def random_stuff_to_do():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Slept 1 second")

task1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = random_stuff_to_do)
task2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = random_stuff_to_do)

task1.start()
task2.start()

task1.join() #This part is usefull only if you want to wait for your tasks to end 
task2.join() #before the program to continue.

print("Task 1 and 2 done at the same time")
```

Comment: Using external process to print some data in console is not the best option...

Comment: I believe that the `multiprocessing` module is already installed by default. No need for `pip install multiprocessing`